# List of specific files in a directory using `dir` command in matlab

Tags: matlab, dir

This questions is regarding `dir` command in matlab.

**PREAMBLE**

I have a set of files: `01.dat`, `02.dat`, `03.dat`, ..., `20.dat`. When I type in command line: `dir('*.dat')`, I will see all my files. If I want to pick only particular files in the range [01-09], I will type `dir('0*.dat')`.

**QUESTION**

Suppose, I need to pick only those files, which are in the specific range, namely: `03.dat`, `04.dat`, `05.dat`, `06.dat`. How can I do it with `dir`?

I need something like `dir('0[3:6].dat')`. I want to avoid using `a=dir('*.dat'); a(3:6).name;` due to some reasons related to the data set. So, I want to specify the desired range at the level of "dir" command only.
Any suggestions? Many thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `dir` could be associated with `arrayfun`: it will apply a `dir` command to each member of a vector, for instance `3:6`. Here, filenames will refer to four files from `03.dat` to  `06.dat`.

Pseudo-code `dir('0[3:6].dat')` could be translated by:

```
filenames = arrayfun(@(x) dir(['0' num2str(x) '.dat']), 3:6);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use regular expressions in MATLAB to filter out what you want. It's not perfect, but gives decent results.

The following code pulls out the 03.dat, 04.dat, 05.dat, 06.dat files:

```
listing = dir('*.dat');
pattern = '0[3-6].dat';

% this is kind of crude, but works: use regexp then pull out all the
% non-matching ones with a call to isempty(...)
notMatching = cellfun(@isempty, regexp({listing.name}, pattern))

% Pull out the the ones that match:
betterListing = listing(~notMatching)
```

Comment: Great idea! I'm wondering, why matlab does not have built-in function that does it. Thanks anyway!

P.S. I would edit: pattern = '0[3:6].dat';

Comment: Well, my optional solution is

a=dir('01.dat'); % temporary entry
for i=3:6  a(i-2)=dir(sprintf('0%d.dat',i)); end;

resulting array is what I wanted. But it also not perfect :(